# How do I remove leading zeros before a decimal point? Excel is formated but the Combobox in my userform is adding them

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I don't want to have leading zeros before the decimal point but my combobox is adding them.

I have my excel column formatted with ".000" and I have tried "#.000"

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    For i = 1 To Sheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    UserForm1.ComboBox2.AddItem Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 1).Value
Next
```

[image: UserForm Image Click Here]

I would like to show .032 and not have the leading zero 0.032

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
UserForm1.ComboBox2.AddItem Format(Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 1).Value, ".00")
```

Comment: That did it!  Thank you